# Audio on onloadeddata event not working in knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

Audio on `onloadeddata` event  not working in knockout

```
<audio id="audio" 
       data-bind="attr {type: activity().mediaType, src: getAttachmentURL()},
                  event: {onloadeddata: function(data,event) {test(event);}}"controls>
</audio>
```

Comment: `data-bind="attr { ...`  lacks ':'.  Perhaps is a typo.  It should be `data-bind="attr: {...`.  And at the end there is `..}controls`, perhaps it lacks a space:  `..} controls`.

Comment: play event is working fine but onloadeddata is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `onloadeddata` to `loadeddata`:

```
    <audio id="audio" 
           data-bind="attr: {type: activity().mediaType, src: getAttachmentURL},
                      event: {loadeddata: function(data,event) {test(event);}}"  controls>
    </audio>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7y8cL4y/2/).  I changed `getAttachmentURL()` to `getAttachmentURL`, without parenthesis, because I have not a function but an observable in my model.